# UITableView footer text alignment broken on iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad

I am not using a custom footer view but somehow my footer ends up not matching the alignment of the cell's title label on iPad, even though it looks right on all phones & landscape. What am I missing? I want the leading of the footer text to match the cell's title label.

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything aligned in the center. What are you referring to?

Comment: The section footer text, it's not matching the alignment of the cell's title label

Comment: OK but it's not centered as you state in your question.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Are you using a custom view for the footer?

Comment: @DonMag I'm not using a custom footer

Comment: add your footer view code so other can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Using a xib instead of initalizing the tableView in code fixed it but I still don't know what the problem was.